# Creating the contour plot of a gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab

How can I create a contour plot of a gaussian distribution in matlab?

Answer (score 3):

Simple case with symmetric sigma and the center at (0,0):

```
sigma = 5;    % just an example value
n = 3*sigma;  % cutoff point
x = -n:n;
G = 1 / (sigma * sqrt(2 * pi)) * exp(-x.^2 / (2*sigma^2)); % 1D Gaussian
G2 = G' *  G; % 2D
contour(G2);  % make contour plot
```

Or in the general case, with a center anywhere and different sigma x and sigma y and a rotation theta:

```
center = [1 3]; % again, example values
sigma = [4 2];
theta = pi/3;

R = max(sigma(:))*4;
[xgrid, ygrid] = meshgrid( center(1)-R: center(1)+R,...
                           center(2)-R: center(2)+R);

x = (((xgrid-center(1))*cos(theta) - (ygrid-center(2))*sin(theta))/sigma(1)).^2;
y = (((xgrid-center(1))*sin(theta) - (ygrid-center(2))*cos(theta))/sigma(2)).^2;

G = exp(-(x+y)/2);
contour( xgrid, ygrid, G)
```

Comment: SO's syntax highlighting is off here, the last row is not a comment of course.

Comment: have you made the assumption that the two variables are independent and uncorrelated in the case of 2D Gaussian?

Comment: @user31820: Good point, yes I did. If that's not ok you'd need to change the computation of G.

Comment: @user31820: I just updated my answer to allow correlated variables as well

Comment: @Junuxx: Click on [this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2793/conversation/highlighting-methods-toolbox-functions) to download a user script that will do Matlab syntax highlighting on SO

Answer (score 1):

The [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) has everything you need.  Check out the section for "Contour Graph of a Function"

There is example code, and all sorts of ways to label the contours, smooth them, etc.